# Relative links stop working after moving wordpress site from hosting to localhost

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

After moving website to my local dev machine, relative links stopped working.  When i click button with relative link /login, for example, browser redirects to

https://localhost/login/

and shows

> Code: Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

While it should have redirected to [https://localhost/сс/login/](https://localhost/%D1%81%D1%81/login/)

*.htaccess* contents on *localhost*:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cc/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cc/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

1. Website files are in *var/lib/html/cc* folder.
2. *SiteURL* and *HomeUrl*
   are both equal to [http://localhost/сс](http://localhost/%D1%81%D1%81)
3. Parmalinks setting *http://localhost/cc/sample-post/* is used, so no problem with navigating to pages.

How to fix this issue?

Tried different *.htaccess* modifications, moving *index.php* to */var/lib*
Nothing helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in `https://localhost/cc` and use a relative lnk with `href="/login"` (relative to current domain/site), the browser (not WordPress) will take you to `https://localhost/login`; if the link is `href="login"` (relative to current path) the browser will take you to `https://localhost/cc/login`.

Relative links work like that, nothing to do with WordPress. That is why many developers prefer to use absolute links, and WordPress too. You can get the home url and append the path you want like this:

```
// See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/
// Outputs http:://example.com/login
$login_url = home_url( 'login' );
```

If you prefer relative paths:

```
// Outputs /login
$login_url = home_url( 'login', 'relative' );
```

And the good thing of using this method is that you get paths relative to current site, not to current path. So, if you are in `https://localhost/cc` you get this result (which I think will work for you if you still wnat to use relative links):

```
// If we are in `https://localhost/cc`
// Outputs /cc/login
$login_url = home_url( 'login', 'relative' );
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It did help for links to use _login_ instead of _/login_. Though for menu items  in my theme (which are derived from Wordpress menu) it didn't work, so the website is redirected to path _link_ instead of _http://cc/link_

Comment: Same applies to any link. So, the question is, how are the menu links configured? What are the urls those non-working links?

Answer (score 0):

As *MrWhite* suggested the following steps solved the issues:

1) **Adding [vhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html#page-header) block to *apache2.conf* configuration file of *Apache*.**

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80>
   ServerName local.site.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/local.site"
</VirtualHost>
```

- */var/www/html/local.site* is the folder on local machine where all the website files are.
- *local.site.com* is  the domain name of the local website
- *VirtualHost* directive has an explicit IP address discoverable by running *ip addr show* in the command line to support multiple name-based virtual hosts on one ip address

2) **Adding the following entry to */etc/hosts***

> 192.168.1.10 local.site.com

To conform to note [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

> Creating virtual host configurations on your Apache server does not
>   magically cause DNS entries to be created for those host names. You
>   must have the names in DNS, resolving to your IP address, or nobody
>   else will be able to see your web site. You can put entries in your
>   hosts file for local testing, but that will work only from the machine
>   with those hosts entries.

3) **Using the same .htaccess from the staging website**

It basically contains the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

There may be much more directives originating from security wordpress plugins. If they use staging website url like in:

```
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://site.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://site.com [NC]` should be replaced with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://local.site.com [NC]`

All the steps were run after:

1. Cloning site code repository to local development environment
2. Importing mysql dump to local mysql db
3. Using [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org) to
   search and replace staging site url with *local.site.com*